# Countable connected graph such that all vertices have degree $2$

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a set $E\subseteq\big\{\{m,n\}: m,n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } m\neq n\big\}$ such that $(\mathbb{N}, E)$ is connected, and every vertex has degree $2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also directly use
$$ E = \{\{n,n+2\}\mid n\in\mathbb N\} \cup \{\{0,1\}\}$$

Answer (score 6):

It is easier to construct such a graph on the vertex set $\mathbb{Z}$, by taking $E = \{(i, i+1) : i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Now let $f$ be your favorite bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$, and define a graph on the vertex set $\mathbb{N}$ by taking $E = \{(f(i), f(i+i) : i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.